# Running local-openid in a subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, openid

I've been using phpMyId to serve OpenID identity that I use on multiple websites. Due to phpMyId not being maintained and having broken down I am looking for a replacement. The server where I used to run phpMyId has Ruby on Rails, so I thought I'd give it a try. After some research I found that [local-openid](http://bogomips.org/local-openid/) suits me perfectly except I couldn't make it run in a subdirectory (i.e. "http://foo.com/openid/").

Is there some easy way to make local-openid run in a subdirectory?

It is a Sinatra application, and I tried to overcome the problem by surrounding the end-point registration code with:

```
namespace '/openid" do
...
end
```

but this doesn't help as some of the code seems to be referring to `request.base_url` explicitly when replying to requests.